# authenticate against LDAP on HP UX

Tags: php, ldap, hp-ux

Trying to develop a program that can only grant access to legitimate LDAP users. PHP has been compiled without LDAP support, so this will have to be effected through the a command line tool.

Is there a way to use standard tools available in HP UX to verify whether a user is entering the right credentials for LDAP authentication?

Comment: Why not simply compile PHP with LDAP support?

Comment: no rights unfortunately :(

Comment: Do not invoke command-line tools from a web application. While this is possible it's a mess. If your task is to develop a PHP application with LDAP access then someone has to provide php-ldap on that system.

Comment: agreed, but that wasn't the question. I'm trying to figure out the syntax for the standard ldap tools so I can throw a user's username and password at the system and get an "OK" or "NOT OK" back :)